# JavaScript: Using an object to iterate over array and keep track of item frequency

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I need a function `mostFrequentWord` to return the most common string found in an array `words`. I would like to use an object to keep track of these word frequencies. Using getter and setter methods seem like the most viable option. Where the setter function is used to change the value for each key representing the word. Then after I sort the object by frequency value I can return the word with the highest frequency. Am I over thinking this problem?

Comment: Yes, you are overthinking it.

Comment: OK so I think I solved it. Yes, vlaz, you were right....was over thinking.

Comment: @BryanSwagerty - You've received a bunch of answers that show you ways to do it. Since it looks like you may be new here, the appropriate thing on stack overflow would be to select the best answer from the ones you received and click the green checkmark to the left of the answer. If you think your own answer is original and better than any of the ones supplied here, post your own answer and select it. But, you shouldn't just leave the question hanging here if the problem has been solved. Indicate to the community that it has been sovled by selecting a best answer with the checkmark.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, I have accepted the answer that seems to have best solved it as of this morning. I also posted the solution coded up in the mean time. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how this can be solved using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var words = ["one", "three", "three", "three", "two", "two"];

var frequencies = words.reduce(function(memo, word) {
    //either start the count now, if this is the first encounter or increas it by 1
    memo[word] = (memo[word] + 1) || 1;
    return memo;
}, {}); // note the empty object being passed in here - that's the initial value for the variable "memo"

console.log(frequencies);

var mostFrequentWord = Object.keys(frequencies)
  .reduce(function(highest, current) {
    return frequencies[highest] > frequencies[current] ? highest : current;
  }, "");

console.log("most frequent word: " + mostFrequentWord + 
"\ncount: " + frequencies[mostFrequentWord])
```

To get the highest value then, it's as simple as running `reduce` again, only this time using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Addressing a comment:

> Is there any advantage to using .reduce() over .forEach() in your first loop? You're just returning the same object every time so it seems that .forEach() would work just as well and perhaps be a little clearer

Well, it's somewhat down to style - both of these *can* achieve the same result. The manner in which they do is different though and I'd argue that for this reason `reduce` has at least a miniscule advantage. Here is why:

1. `reduce` and `forEach` communicate different intent. While they both can be used to achieve similar results, the difference in how they operate does make them a bit biased to some operations.

- For `reduce` the intent is "I want to take this collection of things, go through it and return one thing". It's perfectly suitable to find minimums or maximums, or sums, for example. So, you would use it if you have an array at the start and want to end with something else (though sometimes, you can also return an array).
- The intent of `forEach` is slightly different, though - it is "I want to go through this collection and do something with each item". Essentially, it would be for when you want to do the same operation on each object, say, you might be `console.log`ging them, or validating them or uploading them. In general, you will have one some code that takes one item and does something thing with it and you will just apply it to all items through `forEach`.

2. `reduce` is self-contained. It may not look like much, and it may not be much depending on context, but you have to recognise that the entirety of the functionality is contained within `reduce`. This makes it vastly easier to grasp within a larger context, since you have everything you need in one place. Let's re-write it using `forEach` and I will try to show the difference

```js
var words = ["one", "three", "three", "three", "two", "two"];

var frequencies = {}; //<- instantiation needs to be separate

words.forEach(function(word) { //<- population needs to be separate
    frequencies[word] = (frequencies[word] + 1) || 1;
});

console.log(frequencies); //<- usage is separate
```

So, you make the function one line shorter (no return) but gain one line because of the instantiation of the variable. This looks completely fine now, because it's isolated but in a larger codebase you might have code between each of the sections. And this makes it harder to keep all the logic in your head - if you read *just* the `forEach` loop, you don't have the full context, since you need to know about `frequencies` when you scroll to it, you might not be able to see the `forEach`. What's more, you don't even know what state `frequencies` would be in then you get to the `forEach` - would it have some values pre-populated? Would it be set to `null`? Would it be an array instead of an object? Not only would you have to find the initial *declaration* of `frequencies` but you also have to track down *if* it was changed at any point before the function was called.

Now, with that said, let's re-examine what `reduce` does - *everything* you need to know about how it operates is in a single place. The declaration, all changes and final assignment of `frequencies` always happens in the span of three lines of code, so you will not need to find any other thing for the context to make sense, regardless of how much code you have. Yes, you might need to know what `words` contains, however, the same holds true about `forEach`.

Regarding both of these points, I would say that `reduce` is clearer to understand. The only reason why `forEach` would seem like the simpler solution is if you only ever do things using a regular `for` loop and you need a functional replacement. Yet, the declarative approach has its differences to imperative - a `forEach` and a `for` are different. Neither is inherently *better* but they do have strengths and weaknesses depending on the situation. A `reduce` operation is the better functional approach in this situation.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using `.reduce()` over `.forEach()` in your first loop?  You're just returning the same object every time so it seems that `.forEach()` would work just as well and perhaps be a little clearer.

Comment: I've added a bit to my post saying why I'd go for `reduce`. TL;DR - yes, you could use either but `reduce` has its advantages while `forEach` merely "does the job" without really offering much by itself.

Comment: Per your own description, `.forEach()` is "I want to go through this collection and do something with each item".  That is exactly what the first loop is doing.  It's adding each item to the frequency object.  Nothing more, nothing less.  It's not finding a maximum or minimum or returning one reduced result.  One could have just as easily used a common `for` loop.  I still see not even a minuscule advantage for `.reduce()` in that first loop and it seems less straight-forward with `.reduce()`.  The second loop does lend itself to `.reduce()`.

Comment: `That is exactly what the first loop is doing.` no, not exactly. A `forEach` is intended to do _exactly_ the same thing every time. Ideally it would take a pure function - modifying external state (the `frequency` variable is external) will make the function impure. This makes the function _not_ behave the same every time. `reduce`, however is completely predictable because it takes (effectively) `frequencies` as input, this it's completely pure. This looks like an academic difference but it _is_ what the intention behind `forEach` and the rest of the functional methods is.

Comment: OK, we can agree to disagree.  You're making an academic argument now to try to defend your point.  I'm making a practical and ease of seeing what the code does argument.  You've expressed why you like `.reduce()` better.  I disagree.  Two different opinions.  No need to discuss further.

Comment: Then can you indulge me and explain why you think `forEach` makes things easier to understand? It's a single line less with the two implementations I provided and I don't think that line even makes things any more obscure.

Comment: `.forEach()` is just conceptually simpler for lesser experienced programmers than `.reduce()`.  What it is doing is just simpler - ask any newbie programmer.  `.reduce()` has its advantages when it's added features are needed, but as a plain iterator of an array which is all that is needed in the first loop, it's more complicated than `.forEach()` and requires more thinking to see what it's doing.  That's my opinion.  I don't care to argue with you.  We can agree to disagree if you somehow think `.reduce()` is a simpler mechanism than `.forEach()` for a plain iteration of an array.

Answer (score 0):

It's like this:

```
function inArrayToIndex(value, array){
  for(var i=0,l=array.length; i<l; i++){
    if(array[i] === value){
      return i;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
function mostFrequentWord(wordsArray){
  var h = [], w, a, c = [], m;
  for(var i=0,l=wordsArray.length; i<l; i++){
    w = wordsArray[i]; a = inArrayToIndex(w, h)
    if(a !== false){
      c[a]++;
    }
    else{
      h.push(w); c.push(1);
    }
  }
  return h[inArrayToIndex(Math.max.apply(null, c), c)];
}
var mostest = mostFrequentWord(yourWordsArray);
```

Comment: I don't think this works. Ran it against a simple input and it returned `false`.

Comment: Yep. `mostFrequentWord(["one", "two", "one"]) // false`

Comment: Shortened version now.

Comment: I don't see the point in the `inArrayToIndex` function. `[6, 4, 12].indexOf(4)` will already do the same as that function (aside from returning `-1` instead of `false`), only 1. easier 2. faster 3. it's built in

Comment: Sure, `Array.prototype.indexOf()` will work in IE9 and later, but this should work on all Browsers. Just change that part of the code if you assume most or all your Clients will have a newer Browser.

Comment: If I had to support IE8 or below (and I have do at work...) I'd have already either polyfilled this method or would be using a library to do collection manipulation. I think it's completely reasonable to assume that at this day and age people either aren't supporting IE8 or if they do they would know that they might need to somehow emulate some functions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the input guys and gals. Here's how I went about solving it.

First I started with a helper function:

```
function getTokens(rawString) {
  // returns an alphabetically sorted list of words, removing punctuation
  // characters
  return rawString.toLowerCase().split(/[ ,!.";:-]+/).filter(Boolean).sort();
}
```

Then my main function was as follows:

```
function mostFrequentWord(words) { 
  var wordsArray = getTokens(words);           // setup array for strings to live
  var wordsObject = {};                        // Setup object literal for words + count

  for (var i=0; i<wordsArray.length; i++) {
    var wordToCheck = wordsArray[i];
    if (wordsObject[wordToCheck] == undefined) {
      // word doesn't exist, let's add it as a key and set value pair to 1
      console.log(wordToCheck + " not found. Adding to object.");
      wordsObject[wordToCheck] = 1;
    } else {
      // word does exist, let's increment the value pair by 1
      console.log(wordToCheck + " has been found. Incrementing.");
      wordsObject[wordToCheck] += 1;
    }
  }

console.log(wordsObject);
var mostFrequent;

  for (var key in wordsObject) {
    if (mostFrequent == undefined) {
      mostFrequent = key;
    } else if (wordsObject[key] > wordsObject[mostFrequent]) {
       mostFrequent = key;
    }
  }

console.log("Most frequent word is: " + mostFrequent);
return mostFrequent;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use an object to keep a word indexed count and then iterate through the counts to get the highest one.  Here's a working snippet that illustrates:

```js
function findMostFrequent(array) {
    var map = {};
    
    array.forEach(function(item) {
        map[item] = (map[item] || 0) + 1;
    });

    // find highest word count
    var highWord = Object.keys(map).reduce(function(highestWord, currentWord) {
        return map[currentWord] > map[highestWord] ? currentWord : highestWord;
    });
    return {word: highWord, count: map[highWord]};
}

var words = ["hello", "goodbye", "hello", "hello", "whatever", "something", "goodbye"];

var result = findMostFrequent(words);
console.log("highest count word is " + result.word + ", count = " + result.count);
```

In ES6, you could use a `Map` object to keep the counts instead of a plain JS object, though there's little difference in implementation either way.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is working code.  Run the snippet and see.

Comment: I feel people are just obsessed with their own answers. I think the main purpose of SO is to provide answer and someone downvoted me for providing an external link which provided the exact answer. I could have been cheeky and copied that in here, but I guess SO is a battle ground

Comment: @SenthilNatarajan - There are rules about answers here and those rules have a purpose.  Answers where the entire content is contained in an external link are not permitted here because external links tend to change or disappear over time making the answer worthless as a lasting repository of knowledge which is one of the objectives of stack overflow.  As such, what you posted was appropriate for a comment, not as an answer.  You could have distilled down the content from that article and copied it into an answer if you wanted to provide an answer that follows the rules here.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another solution, which uses [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#sortBy)

```js
var words = ["bob", "bill", "jimmy", "jack", "bob", "bob", "jimmy"];
    freq = {};

_.forEach(words, function (word) {
  freq[word] = freq[word]++ || 1;
});

var max = 0,
    mostFreq = undefined;

_.forEach(freq, function (count, word) {
  if (count > max) {
    max = count;
    mostFreq = word;
  }
});

console.log(mostFreq);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The for each function is native in javascript, but only for arrays. Using lodash, you can iterate over every element of an array, or over every key-value pair of an object. When using _.forEach with an object, the first argument passed into the call back is the value, and the second argument is the key of each pair in the object. You should take a look at lodash documentation. They provide some very useful tools.

Comment: If you're going to use lodash, don't use it only as an alternative to what's already available in JS. It's a waste. `_.countBy(words)` will give you the counts in literally one line of code.